# iOS 12 WKWebview set customUserAgent not work?

Tags: ios, wkwebview, ios12

It seems there is a bug in iOS 12 when set wkwebview customUserAgent. In webView:didFinishNavigation: method I print customUserAgent and compare with webivew.evaluateJavaScript result.It is different.

```
NSLog(@"user-agent is %@"); //Get a custom user-agent
[self.webView evaluateJavaScript:@"navigator.userAgent" completionHandler:^(id _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"user-agent is %@", result); //Get a default  user-agent
}];
```

Dose anyone see the same problem?

Answer (score 10):

Finally, I find the problem is that you can not change the customUserAgent after calling its evaluateJavaScript: metthod in iOS 12. Here is my code

```
self..webView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { [weak self] (result, error) in
            self?.webView.customUserAgent = result as? String + "customAgent" //not work
        }
    }
```

You can initialize a UIWebview or another WKWebiview to get the current user-agent and append your custom user-agent after it.

```
self.tempWebView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { [weak self] (result, error) in
        if self == nil || error != nil {
            return
        }
        if let userAgent = result as? String {
            self?.webView.customUserAgent = userAgent + "custom agent"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 12, if you call like this to modify you UA, it will not work

```c
[self.wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:@"navigator.userAgent" completionHandler:^(NSString* _Nullable oldUA, NSError * _Nullable error) {


    // modify ua
    self.wkWebView.customUserAgent = @"you custom ua";

}];
```

Once you call `navigator.userAgent`, you can never modify it. So you need a fakeWKWebView to get the default UA and set to you truly WKWebView

```c
self.fakeWKWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] init];

[self.fakeWKWebView evaluateJavaScript:@"navigator.userAgent" completionHandler:^(NSString* _Nullable oldUA, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    self.fakeWKWebView = nil;

    // modify ua
    self.wkWebView.customUserAgent = @"you custom ua";

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The above suggested answer doesn't seem to be working for me.

Setting the custom user agent using the below code works on the simulator but not on the actual device, both running iOS 12.0 Beta.

`webView.customUserAgent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", userAgent, @"custom agent"];`

Comment: Did you call the webview's metthod before setting this?

Comment: No I did not call any webview methods before setting this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the same issue, here is the screen capture. Seem an iOS 12 issue with WKWebView.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Add this to AppDelegate

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": "custom value"])
```

Comment: Any explanation on what you are doing and links would be helpfull